# How To increase mail count sending through google app script as it is having limitation of sending 100 mail per

Tags: google-apps-script

How To increase mail count sending through google app script as it is having limitation of sending 100 mail per account?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask has a great guide on how to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to increase quota here:

[Monitor API Quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355)

[image]